# ReactJS- How can I access data from nested object? (fetched API)

Tags: reactjs, json, api, object, react-props

[Image from console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CaNS.jpg)

Hey guys, I am new to React JS and basically web development itself. Does anyone know how can I access the highlighted part of the nested object? I already accessed some of the parts for example:
I already accessed the name using: props.list.name
But when it came to the constellations part, I had difficulties accessing it and displaying it.
BTW, here is the API link https://api.genshin.dev/characters/eula
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map, to pass through all the elements in the array "constellations",

I don't know what your code looks like, it is better to put your own code, and edit your post, and because of you that your code does not exist, I put a simple example for you

```
const constellations = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Dashboard",
    description:"icon",
  }, 
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Dashboard",
    description:"icon",
  }]

{constellations.map(constellation =>(
      <div key={constellation.id}>
        <h1>{constellation.name}<h1/>       
      </div>  
 ))}
```

---

And if you use "props.list", you can write the code as:

```
{props?.list?.constellations?.map(constellation =>(
      <div key={constellation.id}>
        <h1>{constellation.name}</h1>    
        <h1>{constellation.unlock}</h1>
        <h1>{constellation.description}</h1>
      </div>  
 ))}
```

Comment: I would like to do that, but I am new to stack overflow. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

props.list.constellations[your index].name

Answer (score 0):

You can use [object destructuring](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment) for multi level nested objects.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).