# How to access the data inside this object in react?

Tags: reactjs

[IN this image I have to fetch the data in the name key how to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAoX6.png)

Comment: you can do result[0].name. result being the response of the fetch request.

Answer (score 0):

i think this post will help you:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71936347/reactjs-how-can-i-access-data-from-nested-object-fetched-api/71936484#71936484
```

you can use map like a previos post then go through all the elements.

you can do like:

```
{Object?.map(o=>(
      <div key={o.id}>
        <h1>{o.name}</h1>    
        <h1>{o.address}</h1>
      </div>  
 ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

This article might help.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/4-uses-of-javascripts-arraymap-you-should-know

Basically, you need to iterate/map through the items in the object.

```
Array.map((item) => {}))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since the 'data' is an object, you can try this:

```
data['0'].name
```

If you want to get 'name' of all values in an array, you can try this:

```
Object.values(data).map(v => v.name)
```